# dtrace - aggregation of variables passing to funcion from diffrent places where function was called

Tags: c, solaris, dtrace

Sorry for compilcated title, but here is a dtrace output of my script, which I think will help explain what im talking about:

```
        16384                1
        38048                1
        38050                1
        38051                1
        38055                1

    -58632623                1
     -5180681                1
     -4576706                1
     -4498881                1
     -4472021                1
     -4464140                1
<...>
mymodule.so`FuncXXX
mymodule.so`FirstFunc+0x23c
8

mymodule.so`FuncXXX
mymodule.so`SecondFunc+0x4bc
9

mymodule.so`FuncXXX
mymodule.so`ThirdFunc+0x1e1
35

mymodule.so`FuncXXX
mymodule.so`FourthFunc+0x70
39
```

dtrace script is:

```
pid$1:mymodule:FuncXXX:entry{
    @a[arg1] = count();
    @b[arg2] = count();
    @c[ustack()] = count();
}
```

FuncXXX has singature: `void FuncXXX(void *arg, long int p, int q);`

Now, i want to aggregate variables `p` and `q`, but in order where FuncXXX has been called, eg:

```
mymodule.so`FuncXXX'
mymodule.so`FirstFunc'+0x23c
8

            16384                1
            38048                1
            38050                1
            38051                1
            38055                1

        -58632623                1
         -5180681                1
         -4576706                1
         -4498881                1
         -4472021                1
         -4464140                1

mymodule.so`FuncXXX'
mymodule.so`SecondFunc'+0x4bc
9

            49599                1
            51533                1
            51535                1
            52149                1
            52152                1

          -148909                1
          -135530                1
          -121514                1
          -117860                1
               -97633                1
and so on
```

Is it possible to do it ? Or should I trace `FirstFunc`, `SecondFunc`, `ThirdFunc` and `FourthFunc` independently ? But thing is, that in all of that funcions, `FuncXXX` can not always be called.

Best regards and thx for all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregates can be indexed in multiple dimensions, i.e. you can write:

```
@a[ustack(2), arg1, arg2] = count();
```

You can also, if you're only interested in the *caller* of your probe function, use either the DTrace variable "`caller`" (gives you the *address* the probe func got called from unfortunately - not the symbol name) or give `ustack()` a number of stackframes to record, `ustack(2)` just giving you the probefunc (`FuncXXX` in your case) and the place it got called from.

The above aggregation therefore tells you "how many times has `FuncXXX` been called from `...` with a combination of arguments `arg1`/`arg2`".